# Programmatically change rootViewController of storyBoard

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I have created my project using `Storyboards`. The root `ViewController` lies inside a `Storyboard`, I have not written a single code in the `appDelegate`.

Now I want to show a tour of my app, so I want to change the root `ViewController` from `Tab Bar` to my TourVC and when the tour of the app is finished , I want to again switch back my root `ViewController` to `Tab Bar`.

So I looked up online and followed the following points

1) Remove `Storyboards` from app.plist file,
2) Uncheck option "isInitialViewController" from `Storyboards` which is checked in case of `Tab Bar` controller because its a root `ViewController`,
3) Add this code in appDelegate.m file.

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
ProductTourViewController *PT = [[ProductTourViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ProductTourViewController" bundle:nil];
self.window.rootViewController = PT;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
```

But my app crashes with this error log,

```
[ProductTourViewController selectedViewController]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1766a9e0
```

And also I get a warning,

```
Unsupported Configuration: Scene is unreachable due to lack of entry points and does not have an identifier for runtime access via -instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:.
```

Answer (score 176, accepted):

Objective-C:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
UITabBarController *rootViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tabBarcontroller"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow setRootViewController:rootViewController];
```

Swift :

```
 let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
 let viewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("tabBarcontroller") as UITabBarController  
   UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController = viewController;
```

Swift 3:

```
let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let viewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabBarcontroller") as! UITabBarController
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = viewController
```

**Swift 5:**

```
let viewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabBarcontroller") as! UITabBarController
UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController = viewController
UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Or simply like this:

```
let viewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabBarcontroller") as! UITabBarController
self.view.window?.rootViewController = viewController
self.view.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Both works fine!

Comment: So what about removing storyBoard from plist file and unchecking intialViewController. Also the newRootVC is not inside storyBoard.

Comment: no storyboard will be there your root viewcontroller will be changed

Comment: Hello, now on application launch, I made my productTour VC as the rootVC, now when the user exits ProductTour, I want to again shift my root VC to TabBar, how to do that

Comment: use the same code replace with [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow setRootViewController:TabBarObj];

Comment: no its not working, because my tabBarController is in storyboard already. So why to create it once again

Comment: if it is in storyboard then get from the storyboard and set rootviewcontroller. see my updated answer

Comment: Ok , i will try it and get back to you

Comment: I have edited the code and submitted the edits. I am using it in my application.

Comment: just want to note that during `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` application haven't set keyWindow yet, so you should using `self.window.rootViewController = ...` in such case

Comment: Just wanted to say THANK YOU!  Sid you solved a problem I was having for months!  :)

Comment: Last line did not worked for me. So, use [self.window setRootViewController:WelcomeVC];

Comment: Totally unrelated to what I was doing, but your code helped me solve my own problem! Thanks man. Upvote from me! ;)

Comment: This right here was the real killer for me: `UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController`. This `self.window?.rootViewController` never worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

[image] Set storyboard ID for your class in your main storyboard.

```
UIStoryboard *MainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main"
                                                                     bundle: nil];

UINavigationController *controller = (UINavigationController*)[MainStoryboard
                                                                           instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"RootNavigationController"];


LoginViewController *login=[MainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginViewController"];
            [controller setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObject:login] animated:YES];
self.window.rootViewController=controller;
```

Comment: same as above in my question ...please check

Comment: Hello @Mayank, did you get it.

Comment: Guys sorry, there was some code in ApplicationBecomeActive, which was causing this problem and its solved now. thanks everyone, you are right.

Comment: Hello, now on application launch, I made my productTour VC as the rootVC, now when the user exits ProductTour, I want to again shift my root VC to TabBar, how to do that

Answer (score 7):

**In swift we can implement it is as following**

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "StartingPage", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())      
let loginView: SignInVC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SignInVC") as! SignInVC
UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController = loginView
```

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 5 + Xcode 11:**

Make like this:

```
let viewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabBarcontroller") as! UITabBarController
UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController = viewController
UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Or like this:

```
let viewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabBarcontroller") as! UITabBarController
self.view.window?.rootViewController = viewController
self.view.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Both works fine!

Comment: I'm using the first answer in my scene delegate (willConnectTo) it's working but when I kill the app forcefully and open it again then app is not opening. And if change root view controller in app delegate its not working fine.

Answer (score 3):

I use simple this:

```
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"NameOfStoryBoard" bundle:nil];
UITabBarController *rootViewController = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NameOfTabBarController"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow setRootViewController:rootViewController];
```

Comment: How is this code snippet different from the accepted answer?

Answer (score 3):

Just to add to Sunny Shah's answer, this is the Swift 3 version of it:

```
        let mainStoryBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let viewController: UIViewController = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainTabBarController") as! UITabBarController
        UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = viewController
```

Answer (score 3):

> Swift 3 code:

Use below in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions Appdelegate function.
Replace "HomeViewController" with ViewController you want to set as Root ViewController on app launch.

```
self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController")

self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

return true
```

Comment: Thank you for the idea.  This worked for me : <code>    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
         if ProcessInfo.processInfo.arguments.contains("XCUITests") {
            window?.layer.speed = 100.0 // speeds up the test in simulator about 3x 
        }
        return true
    }
</code>

Answer (score 2):

Objective c

step 1: remove main story board from info.plist

step 2: add storyboard id to your view controller in your interface builder

step 3: add the following code to application did finish method in app delegate

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame: [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];


//set main story board
if( condition){
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"StoryboardName1" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *rootViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController1"];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow setRootViewController:rootViewController];
    [self window].rootViewController = rootViewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}else{
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"StoryboardName2" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *rootViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController2"];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow setRootViewController:rootViewController];
    [self window].rootViewController = rootViewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an old article, but I will reply.
I do not recommend the following code.

```
let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let viewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabBarcontroller") as! UITabBarController
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = viewController
```

Because you are creating two instances.
I recommend writing the following code in the appropriate ViewController.

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = self
```