# Goto ViewController From UICollectionViewCell Class Swift

Tags: swift, viewcontroller

How can I go to a UIViewController from my UICollectionViewCell Class?

Here is my UICollectionViewCell Class :

```
class GalleryItemCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell,UIAlertViewDelegate 
{
          @IBAction func gotoView(sender: AnyObject)
          {
             //I Want To Do It HERE... 
          }
}
```

Comment: If you are using storyboards: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22654105/3324388

Answer (score 0):

```
self..window.rootViewController.performSegueWithIdentifier("nameOfSegueInStoryboard", sender: self)
```

This will transition to a view controller of your choice. To change variables in that view controller, you can use the `prepareForSegue` method under the view controller that contains the collection view:

```
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "nameOfSegueInStoryboard" {
            let controller = segue.destinationViewController as! NameOfYourViewController
            controller.variable_name = new_value
        }
    }
```

This all relies on you adding a segue from your first view controller to the other and giving it an identifier in your storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add a seguey to the storyboard then trigger it programmatically:

```
self.window.rootViewController.performSegueWithIdentifier("goToViewSeguey", sender: self)
```