# Back to login screen from any subview of navigation controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7

I am using navigation viewController for Swipping between viewControllers.
I have a  <kbd>logout</kbd>  button on a subview of navigation controller. How can i go back to login screen when clicked on  <kbd>logout</kbd>  button?

Note : `.xib` file contains only two place holders

1. File's owner
2. First Responder

Answer (score 1):

If your loginViewcontroller is rootviewcontroller`and and you have only one`Navigation controller` to reach particular view then in that particular view you can write on logout button's click,

```
   self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

If you have two `NavigationController` between to reach that view then,

```
 self.navigationController?.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

Likewise you can handle multiple navcontroller also.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the very first view in your navigation controller is the login view controller, you can do:  `navigationController!.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(false)`

Comment: Yes, login controller is initial view controller. but this line of code is not working for me. Any suggestion please?

Answer (score 0):

If your Login controller is root controller then you can move like this

```
self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

else

```
//Move to login view
let viewControllers = self.navigationController?.viewControllers as NSArray!
for vc in viewControllers {
    if vc.isKindOfClass(LoginViewController.classForCoder()) {
        self.navigationController?.popToViewController(vc as! UIViewController, animated: false)
        break
    }
}
```

Comment: how can i make login viewController as root controller?

Comment: Make root view controller : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15774003/changing-root-view-controller-of-a-ios-window, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22653993/programatically-change-rootviewcontroller-of-storyboard