# How to Switch from one tabbar to another tabbar in Xcode 8.2.1

Tags: ios, swift3, uitabbarcontroller, tabbarcontroller

I want to know how to switch from one tab bar to another tab bar. 
Here is my story board [I have two tab bars in story board But the problem is that I want to switch from My TabBar to MainTabBar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGW4m.png)

[image]

here is my code

```
 let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let MainTabBarController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainTabBarController") as! MainTabBarController
        self.present(MainTabBarController , animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Do you want to switch new tabbar or new tab?

Comment: no I have two tab bars you can see the picture in this link  https://ibb.co/gRuqDv

Comment: ok, There are 2 tabbars in pic, left(with one tab) and right(with 5 tabs),
from which tabbar you want to switch another tabbar?

Comment: from the first tabbar (one tab) to (5 tab)

Comment: So on click of your button on firsttabbar'v viewcontroller perform above method you have added. Try `animated: false` if you want no animation.

Comment: the problem is that these tab bars classes are UItabbarcontroller and I have changed their class from view controller to UItabbarcontroller

Comment: Provide some detail on when do you want to show the other `tabBarController`.

Comment: @SaeedRahmatolahi Please provide more details, in question.

Comment: I Want to use the first tabbar for launching program for first time and use the second tabbar for other times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the question is different from [where this code is taken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22653993/programatically-change-rootviewcontroller-of-storyboard):

You need to change your `rootViewController`

```
let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let viewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabBarcontroller") as! UITabBarController
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = viewController
```

If above doesn't work, try :

```
let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let viewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabBarcontroller") as! UITabBarController
 let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
 appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = viewController
```

Comment: these pages class are not view controller they are UITabBarController

Comment: @SaeedRahmatolahi don't you see **as! UITabBarController** in the code?

Answer (score 0):

There must be some kind of relationship between those two tab bar controllers at least.
You can:

1. Present modaly tab bar controller 1 from tab bar controller 2 and dismiss it when you want to switch.
2. Use a UINavigationController as parent for both and use push and pop to switch between tab bar controller 1 and 2.
3. Use a UIPageViewController as parent
4. Use your own customer container view controller as parent. This way is the most flexible but the one with most effort to put in as well.