# Navigation Bar Disappears Change Root ViewController and then reassign

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, rootview

I've made the launch screen the root view while my app makes a request to firebase and then reassign the root view once the request has been completed. Unfortunately when I do this my navigation bar disappears or is covered up by the new root view. When I run the simulator I can see the navigation bar briefly and then it get covered up by my TableViewController. How do I keep this from happening?

Here is my code from the AppDelegate where I make all of this happen:

```
    var window: UIWindow?
let searchManager = SearchManager()

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    makeRootViewLaunchScreen()
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    searchManager.getMosaicTitles { results in
        self.searchManager.listOfMosaics = results
        self.stopDisplayingLaunchScreen()
    }
    // Adds border to bottom of the nav bar
    UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage.imageWithColor(color: UIColor(red:0.00, green:0.87, blue:0.39, alpha:1.0))
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return true
}

func makeRootViewLaunchScreen() {
    let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "LaunchScreen", bundle: nil)
    let viewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "launchScreen")
    UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = viewController
}

func stopDisplayingLaunchScreen() {
    let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let viewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "centralViewController") as? SearchResultsTableViewController
    viewController?.searchManager = searchManager
    UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = viewController
    UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
}
```

As you can see I tried to use `UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false` to force the navigation bar to appear but it doesn't. My app still looks like this: [image: what it looks like with missing navigation bar]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting a `UIViewController` as your Root controller. What you want to do is set a `UINavigationController` as your Root controller.

Either create a new navigation controller in your storyboard and load that one instead of loading "centralViewController", or modify your function like this:

```
func stopDisplayingLaunchScreen() {
    let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    if let viewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "centralViewController") as? SearchResultsTableViewController {

        viewController.searchManager = searchManager

        // create a new UINavigationController
        let newNavVC = UINavigationController()

        // set the "root" VC of the NavVC to your SearchResultsTableViewController
        newNavVC.setViewControllers([viewController], animated: false)

        // use the new NavVC as the new rootViewController
        UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = newNavVC
        UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false

    }
}
```

Note: not tested, but this should get you on your way.

**Edit: Another approach...**

Instead of swapping the root controller of the key window, create a ViewController that indicates you are initializing / retrieving your data. That VC can be the "root" of a Navigation Controller.

Put your `searchManager.getMosaicTitles` function in *that* VC. When it has finished, *replace* the current "launch" controller in your Nav Controller with your TableVC. It will look something like this:

```
// note: searchManager will have to be a reference back to AppDelegate.searchManager
searchManager.getMosaicTitles { results in
    self.searchManager.listOfMosaics = results

    let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    if let viewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "centralViewController") as? SearchResultsTableViewController {

        viewController.searchManager = searchManager

        // replace the current Nav VC stack with the new SearchResultsTableViewController
        self.navigationController.setViewControllers([viewController], animated: false)

    }
}
```

Comment: When I use the code above and run it in the simulator their is a brief moment when you can see my old navigation bar and then the new one appears. How do I fix that? Do I delete the old navigation controller?

Comment: Not sure... if I were you, I'd replace the current View Controller in the current Navigation Controller, instead of replacing the `.keyWindow?.rootViewController`

Comment: There is also an annoying lag where the navigation bar loads and then the user sees the tableview appear.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by "replace the current View Controller in the current Navigation Controller, instead of replacing the `.keyWindow?.rootViewController`" do you mind clarifying?

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the lag between when the navigation bar controller appears and the tableView appears check out the following. [Prevent navigation bar from disappearing without lag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46775381/using-notificationcenter-observer-to-handle-asynchronous-requests/46776864?noredirect=1#comment80589149_46776864)