# Swift How to present Tabbar on Button click

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

In my project i want to present Tabbar on button click, now i have already created tabbar and i give identity name as "tabbar" that i show you in below image

[image]

so now i am using below code to call Tab bar controller but i am not getting it.

```
 let tabbar: UITabBarController? = (storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabbar") as? UITabBarController)

 navigationController?.pushViewController(tabbar, animated: true)
```

can you guys suggest me what i need to do and which code is useful to me to present Tabbar controller.

For more specification : i added below image in which there is blue button in one viewController i want to present tab bar controller on click of that blue button

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Emed the tab bar in a navigation controller

Comment: i already create tab with it but now i want to call that tab bar controller on button click

Comment: You navigation controller or storyboard object is nil

Comment: @BhaumikJoshi i am not sure, but i don't think so you can push a tab bar in navigation stack, instead on button click make it the root controller.

Comment: @TusharSharma i don't have more idea that u told can you give me detailed idea.

Comment: just tell me one thing that what i can write on button click ? @TusharSharma

Comment: @BhaumikJoshi check this and apply-: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22653993/programmatically-change-rootviewcontroller-of-storyboard

Comment: I think updated answer may now solve your problem - https://stackoverflow.com/a/47794162/5638630

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this and see:

 **Using Storyboard Segue:** Connect your segue as present modally with your action button.

[image]

**Programatically**: Use `self` of view controller (UIViewController) and present it modally, like this.

```
if let tabbar = (storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabbar") as? UITabBarController) {
    self.present(tabbar, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Here is result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use this, you dont have the Navigation controller over there, thats why it won't push that way, instead, you need to use following code:

```
self.present(tabbar, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be aware that Apple's HIG (Human Interface Guidelines) say that if you have a tabbed application that should be the root-level navigation for the entire app. you're not supposed to do what you are trying to do from a human interface perspective.

That said, it should be technically possible.

My guess is that you don't have a navigation controller.

Use the debugger to check the value of `self.navigationController`, or add a print statement:

```
 let tabbar: UITabBarController? = (storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabbar") as? UITabBarController)
 print("navigationController = \(navigationController)")
 print("tabbar = \(tabbar)")

 navigationController?.pushViewController(tabbar, animated: true)
```

If either `navigationController` or `tabbar` displays as nil, that's your problem.

Comment: i am having navigation controller in my project

Comment: Then ,may your storyboard doesn't access main.Storyboard

Comment: No no everything is working properly just i don't have idea about how to presenting that tab bar controller on button click.

Comment: So link your button to an IBAction (not a segue) and then put the code you posted in the function that IBAction calls.

Comment: here if I don't want to pushViewcontroller,just wants to switch controller with tabbar visible.how can we achieve this?@DuncanC

Answer (score 0):

Select the viewController from which the button click triggered and Select Editor form xcode menu->Embed In->NavigationController.

then write this in button action

```
   let tabbar: UITabBarController? = (self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabbar") as? UITabBarController)

    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(tabbar!, animated: true)
```

Comment: here if I don't want to pushViewcontroller,just wants to switch controller with tabbar visible.how can we achieve this??@Sh_Khan

Answer (score 0):

According to your images I think that your tabBarController has no back button. Means user cannot go back.

If that is the case you can do this.

```
    let tabBar = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabBar")
   let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = tabBar
```