# Swift - Shake gesture dismisses the child view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, segue, uiapplication

I have two view controllers which are defined in storyboard as,

```
UIViewController -> (Show Detail Segue) -> UITabBarController
```

My problem is; I am using a library called `netfox` to debug my `HTTP` requests. And this librarie's `UI` is being triggered by `Shake Gesture`. But when I come to the `UITabBarController` `Shake Gesture` on the simulator does not work at first time. At the second time it dismisses the  `ViewController` that is currently on the screen and obviously a child of `UITabBarController` and goes back to the initial `UIViewController`. This is exactly like connecting two `ViewController`s with `modal` segue and calling `self.dismiss()` from the child one.

I tried to change `rootViewController` of the `UIApplication` by,

```
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow.rootViewController = self
```

in the `viewDidLoad()` method of the `UITabBarController` and it worked. However, for this solution, the items(buttons, titles) in the `UINavigationBar` of any `UINavigationController` that is the child of `UITabBarController` are missing.

I have no idea why this is happening. If someone helps me while I am solving this, I would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier:_)
```

calling this in the `UIViewController` have worked:

```
let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let viewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("tabBarcontroller") as UITabBarController  
UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController = viewController;
```

Respect to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22654105/1404324).