# TableViewcontroller.xib created by me should be initial controller

Tags: swift, uitableview, nib, rootviewcontroller

I have created `TableViewController` by xib not on storyboard. I have view controller which loads by default. Now I want that `TableViewController` as root controller. Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Programmatically change rootViewController of storyBoard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22653993/programmatically-change-rootviewcontroller-of-storyboard)

Comment: load xib in appdelegate and assign the load xib uiviewcontroller to navigation rootview controller

Comment: here i am using xib .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {        
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)  
    let navigationController: UINavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: YourViewController()) //where YourViewController is name of viewController which you want to use as rootViewController
    self.window?.rootViewController = navigationController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1 first register you xib in particular viewController in which you want to load.
by register.nibLod
2 then in AppDelegate in - didFinish method make your that particular viewController as rootviewcontroller.